# Live Server extension is not auto-reloading with WSL2

Tags: html, vscode-remote, wsl-2

I'm having an issue with the Live Server extension for VS Code (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer). I'm using WSL 2 for my programming and I have my GitHub repos saved in the Linux filesystems:

\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\myName\Files\GitHub\CSS-My-Site

The issue is that when I make any changes in my project and save, the web page does not automatically reload the way it's supposed to. Now, when I initially run Live Server it does indeed open up my browser and display my page. It just doesn't update after that, I have to refresh manually.

I'm guessing it has something to do with WSL2 because if I move my project folder to my Windows desktop, Live Server works perfectly. I've tried 3 different projects from within the Linux filesystems and none of them update automatically. I've moved all 3 to my desktop, and they auto-refresh just fine. I've also uninstalled and reinstalled the extension, and reinstalled VS Code as well.

I've gone through a couple of posts but none of them seem to have my specific issue. The 2 most relevant were:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting
- https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/452

I am running Mullvad VPN and also tried turning it off and the issue persisted. My system information is below:

Edition Windows 10 Home

Version 20H2

Installed on ‎11/‎13/‎2020

OS build 19042.630

Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.31.0

Answer (score 3):

It seems WSL doesn't support live reload if the file is in another OS. Please refer the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9426).
The solution is to keep the source and execution in the same place.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem just by changing the extension, now I use "Five Server"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by looking for the local ip of my machine using ifconfig in the terminal, copy the ip, paste it in my browser and then  :5500